# How to efficiently design a system that stores image data corresponding to a coordinate system?

Tags: python, image-processing, data-structures, mapping, system-design

I am building a device that uses a motorized stage and camera to raster scans a sample and store their images, for downstream visualization or perception tasks.

I have attached an image for illustration.[image] (in the image, red and yellow squares are images that map the sample area. Red square maps smaller area, and yellow square maps a larger area)

The stage has its own coordinate system (black dots), which can be mapped to the image data, as each image will have variable number of black dots (>1) in them depending on their magnification (red or yellow dots).

I have been wondering how I could design a system where I'll be able to store these images. My stage coordinate system extends from -50,000 to + 50,000 with a stepsize of 0.1, so it wouldn't be useful to create a reference array of 500k * 500k size to map each point to any pixels that might belong to those points.

I'm trying to do this in python.

Comment: Perhaps try a k-Dimensional Tree? I'm still not completely sure what you're trying to do, but it seems like a good place to use a k-Dimensional Tree, assuming I understand the question correctly.

Comment: I'm trying to map a sample area in different physical resolution (using different magnification lenses). I want an abstract data-structure that will allow me to work with these different representation of data - where I have a physical area for which there is a 10x image, and a 100x image. Kind of like google maps with different zoom levels.

Comment: perhaps the heirarchal Pyramid Representation?

Comment: I think I'm looking for something like a hierarchical coordinate system for images. Thanks!

Comment: Something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UILoSqvIM2w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are well-known techniques for addressing such problems.

Define an underlying spatial coordinate system in `mm`
or some other convenient unit of measure.

Define three (invertible) functions (black, red, yellow)
that will convert back and forth between spatial coords and pixel coords.
It sounds like linear functions will suffice.
If there is noise in your measurements you might find that discretizing
by setting low order bits to zero is convenient.

You will take multiple photos and store them in a filesystem.
Base the filename on the spatial coordinate of the center pixel.
Compose the name in this way:

Let `x_bits` be spatial X coordinate, with MSB first.
Similarly for `y_bits`.
Let filename be alternating X and Y bits,
so e.g. the coord (0, 3) at two-bit resolution becomes `"0101"`.
Turn groups of four bits into hex nybbles,
and treat early parts of filename as directory names,
as you find convenient.

Now at query time, nearby images of different resolutions all appear together.

Alternatively, use arbitrary filenames,
and store coordinate + filename in a postgres [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html) table.
Then `geometry` queries like ST_Distance or ST_Within
will efficiently retrieve relevant images,
using a technique similar to the "interleaved bits" quadtree approach I outlined above.